# Why azure storage table explorer returning wrong result?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-table-storage

[image]

As we see there i filtered the result so i get rows where gps_speed > 150,
but i get gps_speed that eqauls to (25,24,27,...),
I thought maybe the explorer have a bug so i typed script to do the same job still get the same result

```
async function speed1Query(carId,continuationToken){
    speed = "150"
return new Promise((resolve ,reject)=>{
    query = new azure.TableQuery()
    .select(['*'])
    .where('gps_speed gt ?',speed);
    tableSvc.queryEntities('eventsdata', query, continuationToken, (error, results)=> {
        if(!error){
            resolve(results); 
        }else{
            reject(error);
        }
      });
})
}
async function speed1(carId){
    var continuationToken = null;
    do{
        var results =  await speed1Query(carId, continuationToken);
        continuationToken = results.continuationToken;
        
    }
    while(continuationToken!=null);
    return results;
}
async function show(){
      result1 = await speed1("1");
      console.log(result1.entries.length);
      
  }
```

This is what i get when i run the code

> 247

Which is the same number of rows Azure Explorer return.

Comment: What is the data type of “speed” attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the type of the column in your filter. Its doing an alphabetical filtering. In case of strings, "25" > "150".

Comment: i tried you solution but unfortunately i'm still getting the same result

Comment: If the underlying datatype of the column gps_speed is string, then you will get the same result as well.